# Select2 support for quick option filtering via a search box

Tags: java, javascript

This is my code but iam not able to get the required select2 
    with support for quick option filtering via a search box.

```
<link href="jsps/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jsps/css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jsps/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="jsps/js/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsps/js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsps/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert( 'You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery );
    alert("ready");
    $("#e1").select2();
});

<select id="e1" >
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="GL">Germany</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

plz help and let me know where iam doing the mistake

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is not in `script` tags?

Comment: I gave. Thanks for help.Problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

Put the jQuery code inside the `<scirpt>` tag,

```
<link href="jsps/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jsps/css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jsps/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="jsps/js/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsps/js/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsps/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        alert( 'You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery );
        alert("ready");
        $("#e1").select2();
    });
</script>

<select id="e1" >
    <option value="0">select</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="GL">Germany</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

[working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/hq53nbLg/6/)